# A biased dice is thrown 4 times

Tags: probability

A biased dice for which the probability of getting the number 6 is $\frac{1}{6}$ , if it is thrown 4 times .Find the probability of getting at least one 6 ?
My turn :
The probability of getting one 6 at least is equivalent to 1 - the probability of not getting any 6 = $$1- (\frac{5}{6}\times \frac{5}{6}\times \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{5}{6}) = \frac{671}{1296}$$ 
Is the solution correct ?

Comment: From the description I would be inclined to think that the die is fair after all, since $\frac16$ is the natural probability.

Comment: Your answer is correct. You basically used inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: I think there no evidence says that it is natural , may be the other faces have different probabilities @Parcly Taxel

Comment: @HussienMohamed which makes it all the more important to use your logic, as it relies only on the one known!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can visualize it quite nicely with a tree.

The sum of all probabilities must be $1$. Not getting at least one $6$ is equivalent to getting a non-$6$ on every roll. The probability for rolling "not a six" is $1-\frac{1}{6} = \frac{5}{6}$. As the outcome "not six" would have to happen 4 times in a row, we get that the probability of rolling "not six" on **every** roll is $(\frac{5}{6})^4$, therefore all **other** possibilities must be $1-(\frac{5}{6})^4$ so that the sum of all possibilities is $1$.